# PHP issue insert with auto_increment

Tags: php, pdo

I'm pretty new to PHP code.
I have a tabel that I want to insert in to but for some reason the insert statement does not work. The tabel has an ScanID column that AUTO_INCREMENT 's.  I've tried a few things like just leaving the ScanID out of the statement but that didn't work either ( I also tried swapping the NULL with ' '). I was able to insert in to other tables where there isn't an ID that AUTO_INCREMENT's so my pretty sure that my connection works.

```
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file("someFile.xml");
$con =new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testDB",'root','');



$ScanType="someType";
$start_date=$xml ->start_datetime;
$end_date=$xml ->finish_datetime;

$TargetTargetID="1";
$stmt=$con->prepare('insert into
Scan(ScanID, ScanType, start_date, end_date, TargetTargetID) values
(:ScanID, :ScanType, :start_date, :end_date, :TargetTargetID)');
$stmt->bindValue('ScanID',NULL);
$stmt->bindValue('ScanType',$ScanType);
$stmt->bindValue('start_date',$start_date);
$stmt->bindValue('end_date',$end_date);
$stmt->bindValue('TargetTargetID',$TargetTargetID);
$stmt->execute();

$ScanID=$con->lastInsertId();
echo $ScanID;
?>
```

EDIT: this worked for me

```
$stmt=$con->prepare('insert into
Scan(ScanType, start_date, end_date, TargetTargetID) values
(:ScanType, :start_date, :end_date, :TargetTargetID)');

$stmt->bindValue('ScanType',$ScanType);
$stmt->bindValue('start_date',$start_date);
$stmt->bindValue('end_date',$end_date);
$stmt->bindValue('TargetTargetID',$TargetTargetID);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Primary key columns don't accept null values, so either way you have to give a unique value for each new insert

Comment: OP says `I've tried a few things like just leaving the ScanID out of the statement but that didn't work either `

Comment: Query need to be :- `$stmt=$con->prepare('insert into
Scan(ScanType, start_date, end_date, TargetTargetID) values
(:ScanType, :start_date, :end_date, :TargetTargetID)');` and remove `$stmt->bindValue('ScanID',NULL);` completely and then try please.

Comment: I tried that but the insert statement still doesn't work. I don't get any error and nothing happens.

Comment: Generic hints: 1) You need to configure PDO to throw exceptions on error (it doesn't by default). 2) You are using the most verbose syntax for prepared statements (not bad or good, but you might be unaware).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I configured PDO to throw exceptions and the problem is inside the database.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself correctly. Those were hints to help you with development, not to address this specific issue.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you, the tips helped me to find the issue.

Comment: If you figured out the problem and it's not in the answer below, please post it as an answer and accept it so we can all learn from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to pass auto increment column value in insert query just remove from columns and values to

```
$stmt=$con->prepare('insert into
Scan(ScanType, start_date, end_date, TargetTargetID) values
(:ScanType, :start_date, :end_date, :TargetTargetID)');
```

Remove from bind values

```
$stmt->bindValue('ScanID',NULL);
```